# How can I allow a user to rename a Tree VIew Node in Silverlight using F2 much like explorer

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I am using Silverlight 3.0 and I have a TreeView with a bunch of nodes.

I want users to be able to click on a Add node button and add a node which is simple enough.
However I also want users to be able to rename the node in the TreeView by selecting a node and pressing F2.

Is this do-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is possible because the [Telerik RadTreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeView/NodeEditing) does it (and it is based on the MS TreeView under the hood).

The likely solution with a normal TreeView will probably involve catching the keydown event on the TreeView to get F2 then create a TextBox from code (positioned over the selected tree node).

Comment: yeah thats waht I ended up doing I set the content of the treeviewitem to  a textbox